# Allow two html tags in node titles

Tags: nodes

How I can allow two html tags `<sup>` and `<sub>` in node title of all content types.

Or may be is there some module for BB tags which allow using BB-codes in title?

Or my ba is there some hook for preprocess all titles?

Comment: ^ although not an EXACT duplicate, you should be able to get what you need form that question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables)
```

makes available in your node.tpl the variable $title, so you can wrap this as you like in your node.tpl theme file.

Comment: but if I do it in `template_preprocess_node`, this changes affect only node and in admin panel node titles will not affects http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/2183/47sj.png

Comment: I am suggesting wrap $title variable with your html tags in the node.tpl file to show the title as you like.

Comment: ok. But how I can do that title changes in admin panel?